# Replacement for VersionCountDisabler() in Sitecore 9.3?

Tags: glass-mapper

We are working on upgrading our solution from Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3 and we came across with the `VersionCountdisabler()` which is used for the purpose of fallback operation on 8.2 code.

Below is the sample code:

```
        using (new VersionCountDisabler())
        {
           using (new SecurityDisabler())
           {
            return
                _sitecoreContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<IHome_Page> 
                (Common.Constants.ContentItems.ImpersonatePageId.Guid);
           }
        }
```

And on our research we were not able to find any alternative for this method..Could anyone suggest an alternative for this method `VersionCountdisabler()`  ?

Comment: https://www.netzkern.de/en/blog/shared-field-mapping-glassmapper-v5

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has been moved to the GetOptions that can be passed to the GetItem function, so you can remove the `using (new VersionCountDisabler())` and use the getOptions where you set the `getOptions.VersionCount = false` and pass these to your GetItem call.